# ORMLite insert or replace

Tags: android, sqlite, ormlite

I am using ORMLite in my android app and there are cases where I need sqlite's `INSERT OR UPDATE` functionality. I am aware that ORMLite has `createOrUpdate` but it doesn't serve my particular case.

I will explain my case with an example. I have two tables `A` & `B`. They have a many-to-many relationship between them which is represented using a separate mapping table `M`. Tables `A` & `B` have manually generated primary keys and `M` uses `generatedId = true`. The two columns in `M` that store the foreign keys to `A` & `B` have `uniqueCombo = true` set on them. Therefore when I get a record from my backend (as JSON) which already exist in `M` when I attempt to call `createOrUpdate` it would fail on `UNIQUE` constraint. The reason for this is

```
public CreateOrUpdateStatus createOrUpdate(T data) throws SQLException {
    if (data == null) {
        return new CreateOrUpdateStatus(false, false, 0);
    }
    ID id = extractId(data);
    // assume we need to create it if there is no id
    if (id == null || !idExists(id)) {
        int numRows = create(data);
        return new CreateOrUpdateStatus(true, false, numRows);
    } else {
        int numRows = update(data);
        return new CreateOrUpdateStatus(false, true, numRows);
    }
}
```

As you can see above, if there is no `id` in the model to be persisted, an update statement is executed which because of the `UNIQUE` constraint would fail, but since the `id` column is auto generated, I don't know this (I can query the table with this unique combo & then find the `id`, but there are a lot many tables like this in my schema and having custom logic to do this for all tables would be a nightmare!!)

To remedy this I am planning to use sqlite's `INSERT OR REPLACE` which on conflict would delete the existing record and replace it with the new one. From [sqlite docs](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html)

```
When a UNIQUE or PRIMARY KEY constraint violation occurs, the REPLACE algorithm deletes
pre-existing rows that are causing the constraint violation prior to inserting or 
updating the current row and the command continues executing normally
```

This is way I thought of implementing it - let ORMLite prepare an `INSERT` statement, then replace `INSERT` with `INSERT OR REPLACE` and then execute the statement. My question is are there any hooks in ORMLite that would let me do this (get the `INSERT` statement)?

Comment: I feel your pain and I avoided all of this by manually determining how to save each object. I created a custom base DAO object that has a save method that "just knows what to do." I did this under the assumption I would use a custom DAO for every entity. It is more work to onboard a new entity but it is simple and gives you full control so as to avoid getting hung up on issues like this.